# Error "undeclared '_finite'" when compiling the SPAMS toolbox for MATLAB on Win10

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to import the SPAMS toolbox for sparse representations in MATLAB, using SPAMS v2.6 (downloaded from http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/downloads.html), MATLAB R2018a, and under Win10. I have already compiled MEX-files with MinGW64.

Errors occur when I ran `compile.m`, it seems that some of the functions/modules (I'm not sure what to call them) can be compiled while others cannot. I have tried to comment those functions caused errors (about half of the total functions), the rest ran well but they cannot pass the tests in SPAMS. I guess those functions were somehow interactive.

```
>> compile
Warning: Directory already exists. 
> In compile (line 150) 
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./prox/ prox/mex/mexSvmMisoOneVsRest.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
MEX completed successfully.
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ decomp/mex/mexProjSplx.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
MEX completed successfully.
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./prox/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexArchetypalAnalysis.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
MEX completed successfully.
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./prox/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
MEX completed successfully.
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./prox/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexStructTrainDL.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Error using mex
In file included from .\prox/fista.h:24:0,
                 from .\dictLearn/dicts.h:36,
                 from E:\xm\data\SPAMS\spams-matlab-v2.6-2017-02-27\spams-matlab-v2.6\dictLearn\mex\mexStructTrainDL.cpp:37:
.\prox/project.h: In instantiation of 'void GraphPath<T, Int>::init_graph(const GraphPathStruct<T>&) [with T = double; Int = long long int]':
.\prox/fista.h:2195:17:   required from 'FISTA::GraphPathL0<T>::GraphPathL0(const FISTA::ParamReg<T>&) [with T = double]'
.\prox/fista.h:3399:39:   required from 'FISTA::Regularizer<T>* FISTA::setRegularizerVectors(const FISTA::ParamFISTA<T>&, const GraphStruct<T>*, const
TreeStruct<T>*, const GraphPathStruct<T>*) [with T = double]'
.\dictLearn/dicts.h:934:51:   required from 'void Trainer<T>::train_fista(const Data<T>&, const ParamDictLearn<T>&, const GraphStruct<T>*, const
TreeStruct<T>*) [with T = double]'
E:\xm\data\SPAMS\spams-matlab-v2.6-2017-02-27\spams-matlab-v2.6\dictLearn\mex\mexStructTrainDL.cpp:268:7:   required from 'void callFunction(mxArray**,
const mxArray**, int, int) [with T = double; mxArray = mxArray_tag]'
E:\xm\data\SPAMS\spams-matlab-v2.6-2017-02-27\spams-matlab-v2.6\dictLearn\mex\mexStructTrainDL.cpp:311:50:   required from here
.\prox/project.h:3157:25: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       num_arcs[i]= isinf(graph.start_weights[i]) ? 2 :  3;

.\prox/project.h:3160:28: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       num_arcs[i+_n]= isinf(graph.stop_weights[i]) ? 2 :  3;

.\prox/project.h:3191:17: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       if (!isinf(graph.start_weights[i])) {

.\prox/project.h:3199:17: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       if (!isinf(graph.stop_weights[i])) {

.\prox/project.h: In instantiation of 'void GraphPath<T, Int>::init_graph(const GraphPathStruct<T>&) [with T = float; Int = long long int]':
.\prox/fista.h:2195:17:   required from 'FISTA::GraphPathL0<T>::GraphPathL0(const FISTA::ParamReg<T>&) [with T = float]'
.\prox/fista.h:3399:39:   required from 'FISTA::Regularizer<T>* FISTA::setRegularizerVectors(const FISTA::ParamFISTA<T>&, const GraphStruct<T>*, const
TreeStruct<T>*, const GraphPathStruct<T>*) [with T = float]'
.\dictLearn/dicts.h:934:51:   required from 'void Trainer<T>::train_fista(const Data<T>&, const ParamDictLearn<T>&, const GraphStruct<T>*, const
TreeStruct<T>*) [with T = float]'
E:\xm\data\SPAMS\spams-matlab-v2.6-2017-02-27\spams-matlab-v2.6\dictLearn\mex\mexStructTrainDL.cpp:268:7:   required from 'void callFunction(mxArray**,
const mxArray**, int, int) [with T = float; mxArray = mxArray_tag]'
E:\xm\data\SPAMS\spams-matlab-v2.6-2017-02-27\spams-matlab-v2.6\dictLearn\mex\mexStructTrainDL.cpp:313:49:   required from here
.\prox/project.h:3157:25: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       num_arcs[i]= isinf(graph.start_weights[i]) ? 2 :  3;

.\prox/project.h:3160:28: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       num_arcs[i+_n]= isinf(graph.stop_weights[i]) ? 2 :  3;

.\prox/project.h:3191:17: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       if (!isinf(graph.start_weights[i])) {

.\prox/project.h:3199:17: error: '_finite' was not declared in this scope
       if (!isinf(graph.stop_weights[i])) {



Error in compile (line 447)
    mex(args{:});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `linalg/misc.h` that comes with SPAMS, near the top of the file, there is the following bit of code:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WINDOWS)
#define isnan _isnan
#define isinf !_finite
#endif
```

This is wrong. `_isnan` and `_finite` are specific to the Microsoft compiler. You are compiling under Windows (and thus `_WIN32` and `WINDOWS` are defined), but you are not using the Microsoft compiler, and thus these keywords don't exist.

Commenting out this block should allow you to compile the SPAMS toolbox with the MinGW compiler. (Or at least it will prevent the error you are getting now...)

Note that `isnan` and `isinf` are functions defined in the C99 standard, and it should not be necessary to define these macros for any modern compiler.

Comment: Thanks! your anwser was spot on! After commented out the block suggested, the SPAMS toolbox was successfully compiled. However, when I ran test_release/test_all.m to test all the functions, errors occured. It seems that there is something wrong with mexLasso function. Detailed info about the error is shown below.

Comment: @muxia90: Do you still have those errors? “Attempt to execute SCRIPT mexLasso as a function” indicates that the MEX-file is not in the same directory as the M-file that contains the help text. Make sure to install the toolbox properly!

Comment: Thank you for the tips. It turned out I did not fully install the toolbox. Now everything is solved.